# How to filter data in a JSON file based on one of the properties?

Tags: javascript, json

So my JSON file has the following format:

```
"ecycle_data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "naam": "Stichting Kringloop Zwolle",
      "latitude": "52.491091",
      "longitude": "6.106703",
      "adres": "Nieuwe Deventerweg 6",
      "klein": "0",
      "groot": "0",
      "lamp": "0",
      "mobiel": "0",
      "batterij": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "naam": "Spar City Zwolle",
      "latitude": "52.511761",
      "longitude": "6.095226",
      "adres": "Oude Vismarkt 46",
      "klein": "1",
      "groot": "0",
      "lamp": "1",
      "mobiel": "0",
      "batterij": "1"
    }
]
```

In my HTML i have a  object with which the user can choose what location he's looking for. For example, when the user picks the option 'Battery', he needs to be supplied with all the locations in the JSON file with batterij === 1.

```
  var keuze = document.getElementById("soortafval").value;
  if (keuze = "batterijen"){

  }
  else if (keuze = "elektronica"){

  }
  else if (keuze = "grootelektronica"){

  }
  else if (keuze = "lampen"){

  }
  else if (keuze = "mobieltjes"){

  }
  else {
    console.log("maak een keuze!");
  }

}
```

I'm now stuck at the part of filtering my JSON data. I've tried the .filter() method, but that either doesn't work anymore or I can't find a proper source on how to use it. My ultimate goal is to get a variable returned by the function in which only the filtered JSON data is included, so I can put the filtered data through my other code.

Thanks in advance!

(sorry for my variables in Dutch btw, 'keuze' means choice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following snippet

```js
let data={
"ecycle_data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "naam": "Stichting Kringloop Zwolle",
      "latitude": "52.491091",
      "longitude": "6.106703",
      "adres": "Nieuwe Deventerweg 6",
      "klein": "0",
      "groot": "0",
      "lamp": "0",
      "mobiel": "1",
      "batterij": "0",
      "elektronica":"1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "naam": "Spar City Zwolle",
      "latitude": "52.511761",
      "longitude": "6.095226",
      "adres": "Oude Vismarkt 46",
      "klein": "1",
      "groot": "0",
      "lamp": "0",
      "mobiel": "0",
      "batterij": "1",
      "elektronica":"0"
    },
       {
      "id": "3",
      "naam": "Hehe bro",
      "latitude": "52.491091",
      "longitude": "6.106703",
      "adres": "Nieuwe Deventerweg 6",
      "klein": "0",
      "groot": "0",
      "lamp": "0",
      "mobiel": "0",
      "batterij": "1",
      "elektronica":"1"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "naam": "Hey yo",
      "latitude": "52.511761",
      "longitude": "6.095226",
      "adres": "Oude Vismarkt 46",
      "klein": "1",
      "groot": "0",
      "lamp": "1",
      "mobiel": "0",
      "batterij": "1",
      "elektronica":"1"
    }
]
};

function changeInSelection(value){
let message=document.querySelector(".Message")
message.innerHTML="";
let filtered=data.ecycle_data.filter((shop) => shop[value] == 1);
filtered.forEach((shop)=>{
message.innerHTML+=`Item "${value}" is available at shop name "${shop.naam}" , address: "${shop.adres}"<br>`;
});
}
changeInSelection('batterij');//for first value
```

```html
<select onchange="changeInSelection(value)" >
<option value="batterij">batterijen</option>
<option value="elektronica">elektronica</option>
<option value="lamp">lampen</option>
<option value="mobiel">mobieltjes</option>
</select>
<br>
<div class="Message"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple lookup function and look up anything.  This even works in very old browsers.

```js
var data = {
  "ecycle_data": [{
      "id": "1",
      "naam": "Stichting Kringloop Zwolle",
      "latitude": "52.491091",
      "longitude": "6.106703",
      "adres": "Nieuwe Deventerweg 6",
      "klein": "0",
      "groot": "0",
      "lamp": "0",
      "mobiel": "0",
      "batterij": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "naam": "Spar City Zwolle",
      "latitude": "52.511761",
      "longitude": "6.095226",
      "adres": "Oude Vismarkt 46",
      "klein": "1",
      "groot": "0",
      "lamp": "1",
      "mobiel": "0",
      "batterij": "1"
    }
  ]
};
var myApp = myApp || {};
myApp.functions = {
  lookup: function(myArray, searchTerm, property, firstOnly) {
    var found = [];
    var i = myArray.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) {
        found.push(myArray[i]);
        if (firstOnly) break; //if only the first 
      }
    }
    return found;
  },
  lookupAll: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    return this.lookup(myArray, searchTerm, property, false);
  },
};

let term = "Spar City Zwolle";
let propertyName = "naam";
let firstOnly = true;
let weFound = myApp.functions.lookup(data["ecycle_data"], term, propertyName, firstOnly);
console.log(term, weFound);

let term2 = "Oude Vismarkt 46";
let propertyName2 = "adres";
let firstOnly2 = true;
let weFound2 = myApp.functions.lookup(data["ecycle_data"], term2, propertyName2, firstOnly2);
console.log(term2, weFound2);

// get array with all matches
let bat = myApp.functions.lookupAll(data["ecycle_data"], "1", "batterij");
console.log(bat);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

You can use it as

```
document.getElementById("soortafval").addEventListener("input",function() {
   document.getElementById("output").value = filt(this.value).map(item => item.naam).join(", ")
})
```

(wit a few tests to see if anything is returned)

```js
const ecycle_data =  [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "naam": "Stichting Kringloop Zwolle",
      "latitude": "52.491091",
      "longitude": "6.106703",
      "adres": "Nieuwe Deventerweg 6",
      "klein": "0",
      "groot": "0",
      "lamp": "0",
      "mobiel": "0",
      "batterij": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "naam": "Spar City Zwolle",
      "latitude": "52.511761",
      "longitude": "6.095226",
      "adres": "Oude Vismarkt 46",
      "klein": "1",
      "groot": "0",
      "lamp": "1",
      "mobiel": "0",
      "batterij": "1"
    }
]

function filt(type) { 
  return ecycle_data.filter(item => item[type] === "1");
}

console.log("batterij",filt("batterij"))

console.log("lamp",filt("lamp"))
```